# variables inside underscore.js template

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, template-engine

How to set up variables  inside an [`underscore.js`](http://underscorejs.org/) template for an app built with [`backbone.js`](http://backbonejs.org/)? I just want to create reusable processed strings. Also, can `underscore.js`'s built-in functions like [`_.escape`](http://underscorejs.org/#escape) be used to process those variables?

```
<script type="text/html" id="templateresults">

<p><%= encodeURIComponent(title) %></p> // this works

// try 1:
var encodedTitle = encodeURIComponent(title); // shows up as regular text
<p>'+encodedTitle+'</p> // this doesn't work and shows up as regular text

// try 2:
<% var encodedTitle = encodeURIComponent(title); %> // nothing shows up
<p><% '+encodedTitle+' %></p> // nothing shows up

</script>
```

`title` is a JSON item (text string).

Encoded output: `This%20is%20a%20Sample%20Title`
Regular output: `This is a Sample Title`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your try 2 is almost right but the tag where you output encodedTitle is missing the `=` at the start and doesn't need the `+` in the string. Should be:

```
<p><%= encodedTitle %></p>
```

Alternatively you could also do:

```
<p><% print(encodedTitle) %></p>
```

In underscore templates, any javascript you want evaluated must be contained inside `<% %>`, hence why your second attempt just outputs the the javascript as a string.  You correctly used the `=` in your sample at the top but omitted it in try 2.

The `=` tells the templating engine to output the result of the enclosed javascript as a string.  If you don't use the `=`, the javascript is executed, but nothing is output.  Underscore's templates provide the `print()` function as an alternative to using the `=`, I dont know that one way is better than the other.